# Using PHPMyAdmin and creating a column which would have multiple entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a database for the first time! The goal is to have a database for users. I'm using PHPMyAdmin on my localhost (XAMPP) to set it up.

This is pretty straightforward for things like "username" and "password", but one of the fields would be a list of activities that the user participates in.

So for instance, "Activities: Skiing, Rowing, Swimming" would be what this would look like on their page.

But I am not sure how to set this up on PHPMyAdmin. I can't just create a field called "Activities" of type VARCHAR(255) because I think it would store their interests in one box, which isn't good because I need to have these separatedly sorted for later access (For instance, I'd need to query all the users that have the "Swimming" activity in common).

What approach should I ideally be using?

Thank you!

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Create another table with 2 columns, the user ID and the activity. Then for each activity add another row. Or depending on what you want, you could add another table for the activities with the activity id and activity text. Then in your relational table you would have the user id and activity id. This would allow you to allow the user to select from a list of pre-defined activities.

Comment: @Mike you should provide your comment as an answer with a bit more details.

Comment: @Shadow I actually have to go now. Go for it if you want :)

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that I want users to be able to type in *any* activity rather than having a predefined list for them to choose from... That activity would be added to the database for later users to be able to see an Autocomplete suggestion of to use if they'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table `users`

```
---------------------------------------
| id |  username  |     password      |
---------------------------------------
| 1  |    john    |  somehashedpass1  |
| 2  |    carl    |  somehashedpass2  |
| 3  |    maria   |  somehashedpass3  |
---------------------------------------
```

Table `activities`

```
--------------------------------------
| id |  user_id  |     activity      |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |     1     |      Skiing       |
| 2  |     1     |      Rowing       |
| 3  |     1     |     Swimming      |
| 4  |     2     |      Skiing       |
| 5  |     2     |      Rowing       |
| 6  |     3     |      Skiing       |
--------------------------------------
```

Then use `JOIN` or Sub-queries to fetch the required data.

Also, you could implement a 3-tables schema to define users, activities and relationships, like this:

Table `users` (no variation)

```
---------------------------------------
| id |  username  |     password      |
---------------------------------------
| 1  |    john    |  somehashedpass1  |
| 2  |    carl    |  somehashedpass2  |
| 3  |    maria   |  somehashedpass3  |
---------------------------------------
```

Table `activities`

```
-----------------
| id | activity |
-----------------
| 1  |  Skiing  |
| 2  |  Rowing  |
| 3  | Swimming |
-----------------
```

Table `relationships`

```
------------------------------
| id | user_id | activity_id |
------------------------------
| 1  |    1    |      1      |
| 2  |    1    |      2      |
| 3  |    1    |      3      |
| 4  |    2    |      1      |
| 5  |    2    |      2      |
| 6  |    3    |      1      |
------------------------------
```

This will be basicaly the same as the previous implementation, but you'll have a better structured database.

Comment: Awesommme. Thank you very much for your in-depth help.